# How can I limit the size of Oracle blob data type

Tags: oracle, blob

In DB2, we are able to set the max size of a blob type column, like such:
myblob blob(10M)

Is there a way to limit the size for an Oracle (12c) blob type column? 
The usecase being, that I dont want to allow attachment size of more than say 10MB.

Reading the oracle documentation, I get an idea of setting initial size, chunk, extent for the blob. But I cant find a way to set the upper limit. What am I missing?

Thanks,
Vishalendu

Comment: You can't declaratively limit the size of the data type.  You might be able to create a constraint on `dbms_lob.getlength` but that may not be particularly efficient.  It would generally make more sense to code that limit into whatever procedure you have to upload documents before inserting the data into the `blob` column.  Ideally, you'd prevent the file from being uploaded if you determine that it's too big rather than letting it die after 10 MB is uploaded.